# MySQL LIMIT and OFFSET messing up my results order

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a big query which is finally returning and ordering everything I want.

I'm sticking pagination in my project, however now LIMIT and OFFSET are in the Query the results are being ordered differently.
Any ideas?

**ADDED MORE INFO-**

My tables are sort of this:

```
ANIMAL                       FOOD
AID   AnimalName             FID   FoodName       BuyOn           AID
------------------            ------------------------------------------
 1       Dog                   1     DogBix         2011-11-27     1         
 2       Cat                   2     Tuna           2011-11-11     2
 3       Rabbit                3     Bones          2012-06-08     1
 4       Bird                  4     CatBix         2010-06-04     2  
                               5     Bird Seed      2011-12-12     4
                               6     Carrots        2011-05-04     3
                               7     Pedigree Chum  2011-02-08     1
                               8     Rabbit Mix     2011-09-02     3
```

And I want to have the following output in this order:

```
AnimalName   FoodName       BuyOn
----------------------------------------
Cat          Tuna           2011-11-11
Cat          CatBix         2010-06-04

Dog          DogBix         2011-11-27
Dog          Bones          2012-06-08
Dog          Pedigree Chum  2011-02-08

Bird         Bird Seed      2011-12-12

Rabbit       Rabbit Mix     2011-09-02
Rabbit       Carrots        2011-05-04
```

So ordered and grouped by animal with future date closest to now.
The animal's associated dates are then ordered by date closest to to now ascending, followed by past date closest to now descending.

The Query I've got is this:

```
$offset = ~whatever page I'm on * LIMIT~

$Query = "
  SELECT *
  FROM animal AS a
  INNER JOIN food AS f ON a.aid = f.fid
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT f2.aid,
     MIN( IF( DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ) >= 0, DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ), 1000000 ) ) AS dateSortFuture,
     MAX( IF( DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ) < 0, DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ), -1000000 ) ) AS dateSortPast
     FROM food AS f2
     GROUP BY f2.aid
 LIMIT 5
 OFFSET ".$offset."
  )
  AS f3 ON f3.aid = a.aid
  ORDER BY f3.dateSortFuture ASC,
  f3.dateSortPast DESC,
  IF( f.buyOn >= CURDATE(), 0, 1 ) ASC,
  ABS( DATEDIFF( f.buyOn, CURDATE() ) ) ASC, animalName;";
```

With LIMIT and OFFSET removed it works as I want.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION?:**

```
$Query = "
  SELECT *
  FROM animal AS a
  INNER JOIN food AS f ON a.aid = f.fid
  INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT f2.aid,
     MIN( IF( DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ) >= 0, DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ), 1000000 ) ) AS dateSortFuture,
     MAX( IF( DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ) < 0, DATEDIFF( f2.buyOn, CURDATE() ), -1000000 ) ) AS dateSortPast
     FROM food AS f2
     GROUP BY f2.aid
     ORDER BY f3.dateSortFuture ASC,
     f3.dateSortPast DESC,
     IF( f.buyOn >= CURDATE(), 0, 1 ) ASC,
     ABS( DATEDIFF( f.buyOn, CURDATE() ) ) ASC, animalName;
 LIMIT 5
 OFFSET ".$offset."
  )
  AS f3 ON f3.aid = a.aid
  ORDER BY f3.dateSortFuture ASC,
  f3.dateSortPast DESC,
  IF( f.buyOn >= CURDATE(), 0, 1 ) ASC,
  ABS( DATEDIFF( f.buyOn, CURDATE() ) ) ASC, animalName;
  ";
```

Comment: Please include your query, expected output and actual output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are usually not what you want unless there is an `ORDER BY` in the same query. In your sample code, the `LIMIT` is in a subquery, and the records in that subquery are unordered. So basically, you get a random 5 rows from `f3`.

Unfortunately, by far the best way I know of for handling this is with windowing, which MySQL does not yet support (AFAIK). You can hack up something similar with a fragment like

```
(SELECT f9.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable as f99 
               WHERE f99.sortkey <= f9.sortkey) 
              AS rank
 FROM mytable AS f9) AS kludge
```

and then having code like

```
SELECT /* lots */ FROM 
mytable join myothertable ON /* blah */
JOIN /* copy above fragment */
ON kludge.id = mytable.id AND rank<=5;
```

Comment: This query is getting a lot more tangled as I go on..
I see what you mean by the subquery records needing to be ordered before they're limited, seems obvious now!
I'll look in to it some more, thank you.

Comment: I'm in job interviews at the moment, and this query is the answer to "Hunh? Why do you prefer Postgres to MySQL?"

Comment: Well MySQL is all I know, but beginning to think of expanding my knowledge and starting with taking a look at MariaDB.. Would you recommend Postgres a lot then?
Edited in a solution that seems to work with the data I have now, but worried about some field it randomly doesn't work with cropping up/possible performance issues now

Comment: The incremental knowledge moving from one DB to another is pretty small. MySQL has neither CTEs nor windowing, and other DBs generally have both—but that's the only new and significant features to master. I don't know if MariaDB uses the same subset of SQL as MySQL, or they added more functionality. (The stored procedure syntax changes from one DB to another, but often in a one-to-one mapped way.) As far as I know, MySQL works great and fast on simple queries, and that's why it has the greater Open Source market share. On complex queries, though, dot-dot-dot…

Comment: Yeah, this project creep has transformed my queries in to these beasts!
Thank you for your help though and I'll definitely look into another database system for next time.
Good luck with your interviews :)